# Contact falls on the wrong path of decision split. Is it the boolean condition or the wrong wiring on the Attribute Group?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

My journey has a Data Extension as the Entry Point. In this data extension, I have information for passengers including `PassengerId` (Which is connected to the `Contact Key` in *Contact Builder* but does not play a significant role in this journey) and a `FlightId`. Using this `FlightId` we, later on during the journey, check whether the flight is canceled or not and based on that we either send or do not sent the next email.

Now in an attribute group of the *Contact Builder*, **Customers** DE (passengers in reality) have a one-to-many relationship with **Flights** DE (each passenger can fly zero or more times).

[image]

Note in the picture above that `FlownTransactionID` (highlighted), is the primary key of the **Flights** table. This column is what I use to check the cancellation status of the flight as the joining column.

Using this *Decision Split* in the journey, I check whether the flight is canceled or not:

[image]

The column `FlightId` belongs to the Entry Point Data Extension (Journey Data) and `FlownTransactionID` belongs to Contact Data. To reach this ID (`FlownTransactionID`), I follow this path in the Decision Split:

**Contact Data > [My Attribute Group] > Customer > Flight > FlownTransactionID**

The second condition comes from the same **Flights** DE as in above.

**So here is the problem:**

When I test my journey, I notice that a passenger with a `FlightId` that is NOT canceled falls in the path where passengers with canceled flights go:

[image]

So either the boolean flag is not verified correctly or the matching of the key columns does not work as it should. Or maybe something else? I am slightly worried whether my Attribute Group in the Contact Builder is not set correctly or is this the correct way to go?

Note that, there are other test passengers with flights not canceled (`Flights.IsCanceled = False`) that continue the journey and do not fall in the ELSE path down. This has confused me slightly more.

Comment: Does this contact have multiple flights? Do you confirm that the other test passengers that did not fall in the ELSE pathdown have only one flight?

Comment: @RachidMamai The contact may have more than one Flight as it is allowed in the Attribute Group. But the `FlightID` in the EntryPoint Data Extension is a unique value and there is only one `FlownTransactionID` in the Flights DB with that value. That is how I check the status of the flight.

Comment: Journey Builder have some random troubles evaluating contact data in test mode. Try activating the journey (don't forget to delete email activities) and check this contact's behaviour..

Comment: @RachidMamai I will do that. Probably do a clone of the Entry Point DE with test data. I will be quite disappointed if this is the case. You also answered my yesterday's question regarding Decision Split activity going berserk. I was glad I finally found a good tool to test journeys on Salesforce but apparently even this cannot be trusted. I will come back to you tomorrow morning when I am back at work. Thank you for now and feel free to write here if there's anything else you can think of.

Comment: Is your journey data on the left or right side of the attribute to attribute comparison? It should be on the right side

Comment: @EazyE oh, absolutely never thought of that. Let me try and come back!

Comment: @EazyE no, this I'm afraid did not make a difference.

Comment: @RachidMamai I have now activated my journey and created a test Data Extension as entry point with people who will fall in different paths of the journey. I don't find a difference between what the Test tool gives me compared to the activated journey. 4 out of 5 people in the entry point fall in the path displayed in the third picture regardless of their flight status. It is either the boolean flag not doing its job or The Marketing Cloud can simply not find the matching flight. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @Disasterkid does the contact who goes on the "not cancelled" path have only one flight on Flights DE? Can you confirm that all the other 4 people have more than one flight in Flights DE?

Comment: @RachidMamai (1) Actually I use only two FlightIDs that I know of for the 5 entry contacts in the entry point DE. This I did just for convenience. Also (2) The matching records with the same Flight ID between the entry point DE and contact model do not necessarily have the same `Contact Key` rather they only have the matching Flight IDs. Could these be the causes of the issue?

Comment: Try using FlightId - FlownTransactionID in the relation between Customers and Flights DE's instead of PassengerId.

Comment: I don't quite follow. You mean use the same customer ID that in the Flight table as the customer ID of the entry recipient? That sounds reasonable.

Comment: @RachidMamai What I will try to do now is to make sure is that the matching FlightIDs also share the same contact key value and not something else. I suspect that the connection does not work as it should. But as you said I have removed all Email Send activities from my journey and activated that with real recipients. I see that the paths in my journey work better than in the test mode. But I would like to see who has taken which path to make sure the journey works as it should. How do I see the entries for each path and not just the numbers?

Comment: @RachidMamai Also I notice that, using this technique of skipping right into the real world and not testing with the test tool, the `Wait by Attribute` become difficult to test because this is not a date you can easily change. Would be glad to know if there is workaround for that as well.

Comment: You can see the entries for each path and not just the numbers by going to the History tab on Journey Builder, chose your Journey + version, scroll down to the "Status" part and check "Entered Wait".

Comment: @RachidMamai Oh thank you! Didn't even notice that being so busy with the problem. / But isn't it right that the same ContactKey (in my case PassengerID) that is inside the Entry Point Data Extension should be found on the Flight table because this is the key that is connecting them together and otherwise the Makreing Cloud will not find the correct match (even though the FlightIDs match)? Of course I will know more by looking at the history of the journey first. But all inputs are welcome.